# Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed from very long url

Tags: c#, http, youtube, uri

This is the actual url to a Youtube video, at this moment if you copy to your chrome browser you may watch the video. But when I try to create a request I get `UriFormatException`.
What am I doing wrong?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
```

*http:/r6---sn-x5jjxnn-ogul.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ratebypass=yes&ms=au&fexp=924615,912522,932260,910207,936330,916611,936117,936910,936913&source=youtube&sver=3&mv=m&itag=43&key=yt5&ip=119.72.195.38&upn=cBXbXj9uR-k&ipbits=0&id=e9b0fb53c92a23c0&expire=1391346085&sparams=id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&mt=1391322689&fallback_host=tc.v17.cache3.googlevideo.com&signature=EC0116EE4A09D80D38ACB1302F6776320D55A20C.518C15D3446E72D5E764D93AFBA0804B9257914F*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The offender was this guy "http:/r". A quick hack for it is the code below

```
 if (url.StartsWith("http:/r"))
            url = url.Replace("http:/r", "http://r");
```

might modify it later for something general

Comment: I found out this error occurs when you pass a connection string which is incorrecrly formatted into the SqliteConnection constructor. Please try new SqliteConnection("Data Source=test.db");

Answer (score 2):

Check your browser when navigating to this URL, as it is redirected to `http://r2...`.

Copy the redirected URL and use it instead:

http://r2---sn-aigeznl6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ratebypass=yes&fexp=924615,912522,932260,910207,936330,916611,936117,936910,936913&source=youtube&sver=3&itag=43&key=yt5&ip=119.72.195.38&upn=cBXbXj9uR-k&ipbits=0&id=e9b0fb53c92a23c0&expire=1391346085&sparams=id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&fallback_host=tc.v17.cache3.googlevideo.com&signature=EC0116EE4A09D80D38ACB1302F6776320D55A20C.518C15D3446E72D5E764D93AFBA0804B9257914F&redirect_counter=1&cms_redirect=yes&ms=nxu&mt=1391323695&mv=m

Comment: thanks for your help, though it wasn't the cause but led me into more investigations. my browser urls didnt redirect but still played. I guess your browser version was asking for a different file format